# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'name' was corrupted

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I've got an interface function in my application:

```
void addShopToList(Tshp **shpHead){
    char* name;
    Tshp *newshp = NULL;
    system("cls");
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s[^\n]", &name);
    fflush(stdin);
    newshp = addShp(shpHead,name,NULL);
    if(prompt("Do you want to add some products?")){
        addProductMenu(&newshp);
    }
}
```

and I get:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'name' was corrupted.
```

When I trigger those functions separately (I mean like addShp() -> it's just adding a new shop to the list), it works properly.
I have no idea how to fix it :/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`name` is uninitialized, so then when you try to take the address of the uninitialized pointer:

```
scanf("%s[^\n]", &name);
```

it pukes on you. So two points:

1) `char *name = malloc(100); // now it's initialized to something, don't forget to free it later`

2) `scanf("%s[^\n]", name);  // shouldn't use the & for a string in scanf`

and a third bonus point:

3) `fflush(stdin);` don't do that. Flushing `stdin` is undefined behavior according to the C11 standard §7.21.5.2 part 2:

> Ifstream points to an output stream ... the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream ... to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

On some systems, Linux being one as you can see in the man page for [fflush()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush), there's a defined behavior but it's system dependent so your code may not be portable.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

The first is that you are passing the **address** of the pointer to the string to `scanf` - not the address of the string. The `scanf` call doesn't know that, so it starts reading data in to the address you passed it, overwriting the memory location where `name` is stored, and the memory *after* it (`newshp`) and so on... by the time the `scanf` is done, who knows what's left? You can fix that easily by removing the `&` before `name` in the `scanf` call.

But then you stumble onto the other, important, issue: currently `name` is a pointer that points to **who-knows-where** - it's uninitialized. Wherever it points, it's not your memory. The fixed call to `scanf` will overwrite that memory - which you don't own. And then what happens?

The solution to that is to initialize `name` to point to memory that you allocate. You can do that using something like `malloc` to allocate a chunk of memory, or, alternatively, you can allocate the space on the stack thusly:

```
// allocate space for 99 characters (plus 1 space for the null-terminator
// and initialize the memory to all null characters.
char name[100] = { 0 };
```

**Sidenote**: you should really try to understand the subtle difference between what happens when you pass `&name` instead of `name` to `scanf`. It will be a very important pedagogical exercise and help you gain a much better understanding of pointers and how your code is translated into something the machine understands.

Finally, you shouldn't call `fflush(stdin)` as that results in undefined behavior. And that's a bad thing. What do you believe that function call would achieve anyways?